Is it neccessary to make unit and integration tests for my model in ML.net?
I am currently working on a ml.net api where i make predictions with my onnx model. I got it tested and it works, however i don't know whether it is neccessary to also make unit tests and integration tests.
Could someone also please provide an example of how the test is made?
Im trying to make unit tests myself atm, but the system can't detect my model for some reason:
System.IO.IOException : Model file "efficientnet-b0_model.onnx" does not exists.
